# Show that the assignment $f(x) \to f(cx+b)$ is one-to-one

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove that,

For a commutative ring $R$ with identity, the assignment $\phi: f(x) \to f(cx+b)$ on $R[x]$, where $c,b\in R$ and $c$ is a unit, **is a one-to-one map.**

To show this, I tried to show that the kernel is zero, so given $f = \sum_k^n a_k x^k \in Ker \phi$, 
$$f \to \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{t=0}^k \binom{k}{t} a_k (cx)^t b^{k-t} = 0,$$

but this implies 
$$a_r (1+b+b^2+...+b^{n-r}) = 0 \quad \forall r=0,1,..,n.$$

However, I stuck at this point; since $R$ is not a integral domain in general, I don't know how to proceed.

I would appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: When you write, "... and $c$ is unit...", do you mean $c$ is the unit of $R?$ Or do you simply mean $R$ is a ring with unit (and there was a typo)?

Comment: @AdrianKeister it means $c$ has an inverse; so it is a unit, not the unity.

Comment: It's probably just easier to prove that $x \mapsto c^{-1}(x-b)$ is the inverse, thereby getting injectivity and surjectivity at once.

Comment: In that case, it is better English to say that $c$ is *a* unit.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Grammatically correct; however, if we are talking about an arbitrary ring, then we cannot have a single unit in our ring, since, for example, $R$ can be $\mathbb{R}$, so mathematically it is quite clear, but thanks for the correction anyway.

Comment: @Randall By the way, thanks a lot for these quick responses.

Comment: Yep, no problem.  It's fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $\psi:g(x) \mapsto g(c^{-1}(x-b))$, it follows that
$$
(\psi\phi)(f)(x)=\psi(\phi(f))(x)=\phi(f)(c^{-1}(x-b))=f(cc^{-1}(x-b)+b)=f(x),
$$ and
$$(\phi\psi)(f)(x)=\phi(\psi(f))(x) = \psi(f)(cx+b)=f(c^{-1}((cx+b)-b))=f(x).
$$ Hence, $\psi = \phi^{-1}$ and the bijectivity of $\phi$ follows.

But I couldn't see how you derived the condition $$
a_r(1+b+\cdots b^{n-r})=0.
$$ Shouldn't it be $\forall j=0,\ldots,n$
$$
\sum_{k=j}^n a_k\binom{k}{j}b^{k-j}=0?
$$ If it is the case, we can show inductively that $a_n=0$, $a_{n-1}=0$, ..., etc.

Comment: Do you have $\psi$ and $\phi$ transposed?

Comment: @Randall It looks correct. Check again.

Comment: Do you compose left-to-right?

Comment: Oh wait, I see.